# make several video files into stream in windows

Tags: windows, file, video-streaming

I have several video files saved in hard disk and they belongs to a whole video. To play them without gap between openning different video files, i have to think of an strategy of making this files a stream. 
Someone suggest me to use pipes in windows but since the pipe file can't be seen, i am not able to play them anyway. 
The other idea is to send the file into some kind of localhost, then i can read it from predefined url using the video player which supports this. But i am not sure how to do this..
Any suggestion would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to concatenate the files together into one file:

http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f

http://ulyssesonline.com/2009/12/03/concatenate-video-files-using-ffmpeg/

https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join%2C%20merge%29%20media%20files

Comment: Thanks~ There is one thing that i forget to mention: the size of the each file is restricted. FAT32 format only support file size below 4GBytes. Will this be a problem if i use the method you suggest?

Comment: I recommend you give all of the options discussed in the links I've provided a try to see if it meets your needs.